# Найти значение ключа в многомерном ассоциативном массиве js

Tags: массивы, javascript

```
        "white": {
            "P": 
                ["5.0","5.2","5.4","5.6",
                 "6.1","6.3","6.5","6.7",
                 "7.0","7.2","7.4","7.6"],
            "K": 
                ["0.232","0.11"],
        },
        "black": {
            "P": 
                ["0.1","0.3","0.5","0.7",
                 "1.0","1.2","1.4","1.6",
                 "2.1","2.3","2.5","2.7"],
            "K": 
                ["0.21","0.32"],
        }
```

Есть вот такой вот массивчик в js. И имеется переменная скажем, var a=2.5;

Можно ли как то оптимально проверить есть ли 2.5 в этом массиве и если есть получить путь, где она находится, тоесть узнать 
white или black и P или K ?

Например 2.5 есть, и мне нужно еще 2 переменные, в которых будет значение 
black и P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var i in ar) {
    for (var j in ar[i]) {
       for (var k in ar[i][j]) {
           if (ar[i][j][k]=="2.5") {
               alert(i);
               alert(j);
               break ;         
           }
       }
    }
}
```